# How do I print a List of anything in Scala?

Tags: scala

At the moment I have a method that prints Ints

```
def printList(args: List[Int]): Unit = {
  args.foreach(println)
}
```

How do I modify this so it is flexible enough to print a list of anything?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since `println` works on anything:

```
def printList(args: List[_]): Unit = {
  args.foreach(println)
}
```

Or even better, so you aren't limited to `List`s:

```
def printList(args: TraversableOnce[_]): Unit = {
  args.foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Why use existential types (`_`) if you can use `Any` due to covariance? I think `TraversableOnce[Any]` is clearer.

Answer (score 56):

You don't need a dedicated method, the required functionality is already right there in the collection classes:

```
println(myList mkString "\n")
```

`mkString` has two forms, so for a `List("a", "b", "c")`:

```
myList.mkString("[",",","]") //returns "[a,b,c]"
myList.mkString(" - ") // returns "a - b - c"
//or the same, using infix notation
myList mkString ","
```

My example just used `\n` as the separator and passed the resulting string to `println`

Answer (score 8):

You just need to make the method generic

```
def printList[A](args: List[A]): Unit = {
  args.foreach(println)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def printList[T](args: List[T]) = args.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a recursive version to practise :)

1 - Declare your List

```
val myCharList: List[Char] = List('(',')','(',')')
```

2 - Define your method

```
def printList( chars: List[Char] ): Boolean = {
  if ( chars.isEmpty ) true //every item of the list has been printed
  else {
    println( chars.head )
    printList( chars.tail )
  }
}
```

3 - Call the method

```
printList( myCharList )
```

Output:

```
 (
 )
 (
 )
```