# getting value from set in scala

Tags: scala

I took a set in scala i.e.

```
var s = Set("ABC","ABC")
println(s)
```

on printing it gives `Set(ABC)`

Is there any api to get only value i.e `"ABC"` and not `"Set(ABC)"` ?

I know that I have defined a set then why does it shows the output as "Set(ABC)"

Comment: `Set("ABC","ABC").foreach(println)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `.mkString(elements_separator)`

eg.

```
scala> val s = Set("ABC","ABC")
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(ABC)

scala> s.mkString(",")
res12: String = ABC

scala> val s2 = Set("ABC","ABC", "APPLE", "APPLE")
s2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(ABC, APPLE)

scala> s2.mkString(",")
res13: String = ABC,APPLE
```

Also see [How do I print a List of anything in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6639377/432903)